# Get the next (Private) Ip address from the Amazon AWS SDK for an EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I've been playing with the amazon AWS SDK (for NodeJS) for the last couple of days, especially with the EC2 part. I was wondering if it is possible to know what your IP-address will be before booting new instances.

I checked the documentation and google but I couldn't find an answer to this.
So before I run the `runInstances` function I have a function that returns me the next `n` ip-address that will be assigned to me if I create `n` new instances right now.

I don't know if this is possible but I can't find anything about this.

Comment: why do you need to know this? avoid fixed ips when possible. it will make your life harder in terms of scalability and all the nice shiny features of the cloud.

Comment: I'm basically just trying stuff and that's why I wondered if this is possible. I haven't found anything online about this so that's why I'm asking here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot predict the private IP address that will be assigned, but you can **specify** the IP address when the instance is launched.

The [`runInstances()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#runInstances-property) command in the Amazon SDK for node.js has a `PrivateIpAddress` parameter that can specify the IP address to assign to the instance:

```
var params = {
  ImageId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  MaxCount: 0, /* required */
  MinCount: 0, /* required */
  NetworkInterfaces: [
    {
      PrivateIpAddress: 'STRING_VALUE'
    }
  /* etc */
};
ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Yes I've seen that field, but then how do I know what to fill in that field :)
How do I know without failing that the IP address that I specified is not already taken

Comment: You will either need to keep your own list and assign an unused one, or use DescribeInstances to obtain a list of current instances and then pick an address that isn't used.